# JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE error using multiple activites and OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runtime-error

I am making an weather app, on the main screen app shows current weather for a city that is chosen and on the second activity screen you can find weather for next 3 days. I have WeatherInfoTask.java that is used to get JSON for MainActivity and MultipleWeatherTask.java that is used to get JSON for MultipleDays (activity)

so the MainActivity works fine and I get JSON and all of the info is shown on the screen just as it should be, but when I click on the button that should redirect me to the screen of the MultipleDays, I am redirected and just a plain screen is shown without data and this error is shown:

E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)

These are my files:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String cityName;
Handler handler;
TextView titleText;
TextView temperatureText;
TextView descriptionText;

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Closing the App")
                .setMessage("No Internet Connection, check your settings")
                .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .show();
    }

    handler = new Handler();

    titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    temperatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureText);
    descriptionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Find City");
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            cityName = place.getName().toString();

            updateWeather(cityName);
            /*Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("MainActivity", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}

private void updateWeather(final String city){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            final JSONObject json = WeatherInfoTask.getJSON(MainActivity.this, city);
            if(json == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error loading weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        SetWeather(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private void SetWeather(JSONObject json){
    try {
        /*cityField.setText(json.getString("name").toUpperCase(Locale.US) +
                ", " +
                json.getJSONObject("sys").getString("country"));*/

        JSONObject details = json.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("main");   /*"main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15}*/
        titleText.setText(R.string.title + cityName);
        descriptionText.setText( /*"description":"light intensity drizzle"*/
                details.getString("description") +
                        "\n" + "Humidity: " + main.getString("humidity") + "%" +
                        "\n" + "Pressure: " + main.getString("pressure") + " hPa");

        temperatureText.setText(
                String.format("%.2f", main.getDouble("temp"))+ " ℃");

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("SimpleWeather", "One or more fields not found in the JSON data");
    }
}

   public void MultipleDays(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MultipleDays.class);
   startActivity(intent);

   }
 }
```

Next one:

```
public class WeatherInfoTask {

private static final String OpenWeatherAPI =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&units=metric";

public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(OpenWeatherAPI, city));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", context.getString(R.string.apikey));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
        String tmp = ""; /*tmp = temporary*/
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        /*This value will be 404 if the request was not successful*/
        if (data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
            /*greska*/
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Next one:

```
public class MultipleDays extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;
TextView day1;
TextView day2;
TextView day3;
Integer dayCounter = 1;
Date comparisonDate;
Date currentDate;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Float dailyMin;
Float dailyMax;
Float currMin;
Float currMax;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiple_days);
    handler = new Handler();

    day1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day1);
    day2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day2);
    day3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day3);

    updateMultipleWeather(MainActivity.cityName);

}

private void updateMultipleWeather(final String city){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            final JSONObject json = MultipleWeatherTask.getJSON(MultipleDays.this, city);
            if(json == null){
                Toast.makeText(MultipleDays.this, "Error loading weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        setWeather(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private void setWeather(JSONObject json){
    try {

        JSONArray list = json.getJSONArray("list");

        for (int i=0; i < list.length() ; i++){

            if(i == 0) {
                String string = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("dt_txt");
                string = convertDate(string);
                comparisonDate = formatter.parse(string.replace("",""));

                dailyMin = Float.parseFloat(list.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp_min"));
                dailyMax = Float.parseFloat(list.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp_max"));
            }
            else if ( dayCounter <=3 ){
                String string = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("dt_txt");
                string = convertDate(string);
                currentDate = formatter.parse(string.replace("","")); //datum u obliku "yy-MM-dd"

                if ( comparisonDate == currentDate ){ //ako smo i dalje na istom danu

                    currMin = Float.parseFloat(list.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp_min"));
                    currMax = Float.parseFloat(list.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp_max"));

                    if( dailyMin > currMin ) dailyMin = currMin;
                    if( dailyMax < currMax ) dailyMax = currMax;

                }
                else {

                    switch (dayCounter){
                        case 1:         day1.setText("Minimum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMin) + "\n" +
                                                     "Maximum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMax) + "\n" +
                                                     "Weather: " + list.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("description"));
                                        dayCounter++;
                                        break;
                        case 2:         day2.setText("Minimum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMin) + "\n" +
                                                     "Maximum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMax) + "\n" +
                                                     "Weather: " + list.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("description"));
                                        dayCounter++;
                                        break;
                        case 3:         day3.setText("Minimum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMin) + "\n" +
                                        "Maximum temperature: " + String.format("%.2f", dailyMax) + "\n" +
                                        "Weather: " + list.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("description"));
                                        dayCounter++;
                                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Next one:

```
public class MultipleWeatherTask {

private static final String OpenWeatherAPI =
        "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=%s&units=metric";

public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(OpenWeatherAPI, city));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", context.getString(R.string.apikey));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
        String tmp = ""; /*tmp = temporary*/
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        /*This value will be 404 if the request was not successful*/
        if (data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
            /*greska*/
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've updated some libraries today in my project(google-services, firebase), and now I have the same mistake.
**"E / StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15 (JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)"**
I'm looking for a solution or cause.
I write if I find a problem. But now I add to your request for help.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 6):

***File ---> Invalidate Caches / Restart*** will help you.

Comment: I tried to do that before asking this question, it didn't work

Comment: This solution never seems to work for me, but going to my AndroidStudioProjects folder, renaming the libraries folder inside the application, then opening up Android Studio usually works. Android Studio finds that you don't have a libraries folder and rebuilds one for you. I suggest keeping the old libraries folder (just in case)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a restart of the tablet will help too